# Script to capture value of multiple cells on a Daily or Weekly schedule?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to the code trying to fix this. I have 2 sheets(A&B).On a weekly basis the data from sheet A should be captured and need to be pasted it in sheet B based on one common column (column A)

**Sheet A** [image]
**Sheet B** [image]

**My Code:**

```
var ssA = SpreadsheetApp.openById('12dmkCZH4V-2g1brKcGen3iD958_39MoBP77ebMtRnlw');
var sheetA = ssA.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
Logger.log(sheetA.getLastRow());
var dataA = sheetA.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
var dataA_values = sheetA.getRange('M2:M').getValues();
  Logger.log(dataA);
// gets spreadsheet B and the range of data
var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1isb3NJJHCyWKOlshHkrOkd_Q_j88LUZu9jux5VbQDwg');
var sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName('Sheet5');
var dataB = sheetB.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
 Logger.log(sheetB.getLastRow());
  Logger.log(dataB);

// loops through column A of spreadsheet A & B and compares
  for(var i = 0; i < dataA.length; i++) {
    Logger.log("A-" +dataA[i]);
    for(var j = 0; j < dataB.length; j++)
{
  Logger.log("B-" + dataB[j]);
  // checks to see if ith value in 2nd row is the same

  if (dataA[i].toString() == dataB[j].toString()){    
    var value = dataA_values[i].toString();
    Logger.log("value:"+ value);
    // used i+1 because index of range is 1, while index of the data array is 0
//     sheetB.getRange(j+1, 3).setValue(new Date()); //set current date for the column as  header
    sheetB.getRange(j+2, 3).setValue(value);

  } // end if
} // end i 

  }
```

Need some assistance in comparing system date and the date in sheet B and copy the content when the data is matched. I had a sample code of date comparison but got stuck

```
function onDate()
{
  var d = new Date();
  Logger.log(d);
  var date1 = d.getDate();
  Logger.log("date1...." + date1);
  var month1 = d.getMonth()+1;
  Logger.log("month1...." + month1);
  var year1 = d.getFullYear();
  Logger.log("year1...." + year1);

//  var timeStamp = d.getTime();
//  Logger.log(timeStamp);
//  var currentTime = d.toLocaleTimeString();
//  Logger.log(currentTime);
//  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(d, 'GMT-5', 'dd MMM yyyy'));
  var ssB = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1isb3NJJHCyWKOlshHkrOkd_Q_j88LUZu9jux5VbQDwg');
  var sheetB = ssB.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dateB = sheetB.getRange('D1:D1').getValues();



  Logger.log(typeof(dateB));
  var dB = new Date(dateB) 
  Logger.log(dB);
  var date2 = dB.getDate();
  Logger.log("date2...." + date2);
  var month2 = dB.getMonth()+1;
  Logger.log("month2...." + month2);
  var year2 = dB.getFullYear();
  Logger.log("year2...." + year2);
//  Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(dB, 'GMT-5', 'dd MMM yyyy'));
//  var dB = dateB.toString();
//  Logger.log(dateB);
//  Logger.log(dB);
//   Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(dB, 'GMT-5', 'dd MMM yyyy'));
  var row = 1;
//  var sheetDate = sheetB.getRange(row,getColIndexByName()).getValue();
  if (year1==year2 && month1==month2 && date1==date2)
  {

    return true;

  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "Need some assistance in comparing system date and the date in sheet B and copy the content when the data is matched"? What is the comparison you're trying to make and what is the condition for matching the data?

Comment: compare columns A (customer) from both the sheets, if it matches copy the respective value from column M (Amount) to sheet B. And also the same script to be run every week to the respective dates columns and once copied it should not change the values. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with a container-bound script and both Sheet A & B in the same spreadsheet, so you'll need to update the `ss` values in both functions, as well as the sheet names.

```
function copyData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetB = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet B");
  var originalValues = getOriginalValues();
  var bCustomers = sheetB.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var printArray = []; // Faster to print all values at once
  for (var i=0; i<bCustomers.length; i++) {
    printArray.push([originalValues[bCustomers[i][0]] ||  ""]);
  }

  var dates = sheetB.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheetB.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var today = new Date();
  today.setHours(0,0,0,0); // Set hours to 0 so that we can compare just the date value
  // In this for loop, we will iterate through all of the date header values.
  // If we find today's date, then we will print the values in that row.
  for (var i=0; i<dates[0].length; i++) {
    var columnDate = new Date(dates[0][i]);
    columnDate.setHours(0,0,0,0); // Set hours to 0 so that we can compare just the date value
    if (columnDate.valueOf() === today.valueOf()) {
      sheetB.getRange(2, i+1, printArray.length, 1).setValues(printArray);
      break; // No need to look any further; we're done!
    }
  }
}

function getOriginalValues() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetA = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet A");
  var originalValues = {}; // Using an object means that searching for the correct value later will be much faster
  var customers = sheetA.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  var amounts = sheetA.getRange("M2:M").getValues();
  for (var i=0; i<customers.length; i++) {
    if (customers[i] == "") {
      /** 
      * This can be optimized depending on your data.
      * In the current implementation, I'm assuming that once an empty value
      * is found in SheetA,ColumnA, then there is no more data. If there is the possibility
      * of an empty row in the middle of the data, then use `continue` instead. 
      *
      * You could also adjust the `getRange()` method to only get the range where
      * data exists by using a `getLastRow()` method, but I find using the A1 notation to be
      * more easily understood. 
      */
      break; 
    }
    originalValues[customers[i][0]] = amounts[i][0];
  }
  return originalValues;
}
```

You can [set up a trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) to run daily, or set up a weekly trigger to run the `copyData()` function every week. (Looks like you want it to run on Tuesdays.)

[image]